# no option for adding new plugin in Heroku WordPress

Tags: php, wordpress, heroku, plugins

I just installed WordPress in Heroku, now I wanted to add the plugin in WordPress but it does not allow me to add the plugin, no option is available for adding new plugin why? please help I'm in great trouble

Answer (score 0):

Heroku is a bit unusual as hosting providers go. The filesystem your code is deployed on is *ephemeral* - any changes you make to it (like installing plugins) will be blown away a) the next time you deploy and b) at least once daily due to dyno restarts. In addition, if you're running *multiple* dynos, making changes on one won't reflect on the others.

What you'll need to do is install the plugins *locally* in your development environment, and check all the added files into the Git repository and deploy that to Heroku.